# Matplotlib, legend with multiple different markers with one label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a simplified plot of the situation:

[image: plot example]

Instead of have each data point marker have a separate label, I want to be able to have one label for a set of different markers. I would like to be able to have a legend like:

```
<triangle> <square> <hexagon> <diamond> <circle> Shotcrete strength data points
<green line> 10 minute strength
<blue line> 60 minute strength
<yellow line> 1 day strength
<orange line> 7 day strength
<red line> 28 day strength
```

I want to do this because in the final plot I will have three sets of data points and showing 18 (3 sets * 6 points/set) marker/label combinations will be messy.

I am using Matplotlib with Python 2.7.

Comment: For people facing a similar issue using Python and matplotlib v 3.0 and above, the answer I have posted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527093/how-to-add-bar-and-line-under-the-same-label-in-a-legend/) may help.

Answer (score 3):

*Note*: This answer is kept up as a guide to the correct answer - but it does not solve the stated problem. Please see the edit below for the problem of Patch collections not being support in matplotlib.

---

One way to go about this, if you want complete customization is to use a so-called Proxy Artist:

```
from pylab import *

p1 = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="r")
p2 = Circle((0, 0), fc="b")
p3 = plot([10,20],'g--')
legend([p1,p2,p3], ["Red Rectangle","Blue Circle","Green-dash"])

show()
```

Here you can specify *exactly* what you'd like the legend to look like, and even use non-standard plot shapes (patches).

**Edit:** There is some difficulty with this method, [matplotlib only supports these Artists in a legend](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#plotting-guide-legend) without tweaking. For matplotlib v1.0 and earlier, the supported artists are as follows.

```
Line2D
Patch
LineCollection
RegularPolyCollection
CircleCollection
```

Your request of multiple scatter points would be done with a [Patch Collection](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/collections_api.html?highlight=patchcollection#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection), which is not supported above. In theory with v1.1, this is possible but I do not see how.

Comment: I am currently using psuedo lines to make my legend. I think I might be able to use something like this (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handler):
`code`

    z = np.random.randn(10)

    p1a, = plt.plot(z, "ro", ms=10, mfc="r", mew=2, mec="r") # red     filled circle
    p1b, = plt.plot(z[:5], "w+", ms=10, mec="w", mew=2) # white cross

    plt.legend([p1a, (p1a, p1b)], ["Attr A", "Attr A+B"])
`code`
to combined multiple markers onto one line.

Comment: @CrazyArm as far as I understand it, you'll have to define a custom shape for the `<triangle> <square> <hexagon> <diamond> <circle>` which is why I gave the solution as I did. You may be able to extract the symbol shape from the scatter plot source (or from scatter itself) and use that with the custom shape as input to `legend`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand how to make an individual custom marker in the legend (a rectangle, or circle like you mentioned), but I don't know how to go about combining two of them. This (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/scatter_piecharts.html) does it by overlapping multiple symbols, but I don't know how they would show it on a legend.

Comment: Also, your code results in two rectangles (one red, one blue) in the legend, not a rectangle a circle.

Comment: @CrazyArm your solution helped me solve my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732845/combine-two-pyplot-patches-for-legend/28735010#28735010. Thanks!