# Multi-color Legend Entry

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like to make a legend entry in a matplotlib look something like this:

[image]

It has multiple colors for a given legend item. Code is shown below which outputs a red rectangle. I'm wondering what I need to do to overlay one color ontop of another? Or is there a better solution?

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Foo')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])

plt.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789191/matplotlib-patches-one-patch-with-mulitple-colors#answer-57791790

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is in fact a proper way to do this by implementing a custom
legend handler as explained in the matplotlib-doc under *"implementing a custom legend handler"* [(here)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html?highlight=implementing%20custom%20handler#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

# define an object that will be used by the legend
class MulticolorPatch(object):
    def __init__(self, colors):
        self.colors = colors
        
# define a handler for the MulticolorPatch object
class MulticolorPatchHandler(object):
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        width, height = handlebox.width, handlebox.height
        patches = []
        for i, c in enumerate(orig_handle.colors):
            patches.append(plt.Rectangle([width/len(orig_handle.colors) * i - handlebox.xdescent, 
                                          -handlebox.ydescent],
                           width / len(orig_handle.colors),
                           height, 
                           facecolor=c, 
                           edgecolor='none'))

        patch = PatchCollection(patches,match_original=True)

        handlebox.add_artist(patch)
        return patch


# ------ choose some colors
colors1 = ['g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y']
colors2 = ['k', 'r', 'k', 'r', 'k', 'r']

# ------ create a dummy-plot (just to show that it works)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [1,4.5,2,5.5,3], c='g', lw=0.5, ls='--',
        label='... just a line')
ax.scatter(range(len(colors1)), range(len(colors1)), c=colors1)
ax.scatter([range(len(colors2))], [.5]*len(colors2), c=colors2, s=50)

# ------ get the legend-entries that are already attached to the axis
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# ------ append the multicolor legend patches
h.append(MulticolorPatch(colors1))
l.append("a nice multicolor legend patch")

h.append(MulticolorPatch(colors2))
l.append("and another one")

# ------ create the legend
f.legend(h, l, loc='upper left', 
         handler_map={MulticolorPatch: MulticolorPatchHandler()}, 
         bbox_to_anchor=(.125,.875))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The solution I am proposing is to combine two different [proxy-artists](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) for one entry legend, as described here: [Combine two Pyplot patches for legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732845/combine-two-pyplot-patches-for-legend/28735010#28735010).

The strategy is then to set the `fillstyle` of the first square marker to `left` while the other one is set to `right` (see http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/pylab_examples/filledmarker_demo.html). Two different colours can then be attributed to each marker in order to produce the desired two-colour legend entry.

The code below show how this can be done. Note that the `numpoints=1` argument in `plt.legend` is important in order to display only one marker for each entry.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

#---- Generate a Figure ----

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.15, 0.75, 0.75])
ax.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])

#---- Define First Legend Entry ----

m1, = ax.plot([], [], c='red' , marker='s', markersize=20,
              fillstyle='left', linestyle='none')

m2, = ax.plot([], [], c='blue' , marker='s', markersize=20,
              fillstyle='right', linestyle='none')

#---- Define Second Legend Entry ----

m3, = ax.plot([], [], c='cyan' , marker='s', markersize=20,
              fillstyle='left', linestyle='none')

m4, = ax.plot([], [], c='magenta' , marker='s', markersize=20,
              fillstyle='right', linestyle='none')

#---- Plot Legend ----

ax.legend(((m2, m1), (m3, m4)), ('Foo', 'Foo2'), numpoints=1, labelspacing=2,
          loc='center', fontsize=16)

plt.show(block=False)
```

Which results in:

[image]

**Disclaimer:** This will only work for a two-colors legend entry. If more than two colours is desired, I cannot think of any other way to do this other than the approach described by @jwinterm ([Python Matplotlib Multi-color Legend Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908982/python-matplotlib-multi-color-legend-entry/31909401#31909401))

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps another hack to handle more than two patches. Make sure you order the handles/labels according to the number of columns:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

pa1 = Patch(facecolor='red', edgecolor='black')
pa2 = Patch(facecolor='blue', edgecolor='black')
pa3 = Patch(facecolor='green', edgecolor='black')
#
pb1 = Patch(facecolor='pink', edgecolor='black')
pb2 = Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='black')
pb3 = Patch(facecolor='purple', edgecolor='black')

ax.legend(handles=[pa1, pb1, pa2, pb2, pa3, pb3],
          labels=['', '', '', '', 'First', 'Second'],
          ncol=3, handletextpad=0.5, handlelength=1.0, columnspacing=-0.5,
          loc='center', fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: By far, this is the easiest to apply.

Comment: A hack, but it works!

Answer (score 5):

I absolutely loved @raphael's answer.
Here is a version with circles. Furthermore, I've refactored and trimmed the code a bit to make it more modular.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

class MulticolorCircles:
    """
    For different shapes, override the ``get_patch`` method, and add the new
    class to the handler map, e.g. via

    ax_r.legend(ax_r_handles, ax_r_labels, handlelength=CONF.LEGEND_ICON_SIZE,
            borderpad=1.2, labelspacing=1.2,
            handler_map={MulticolorCircles: MulticolorHandler})
    """

    def __init__(self, face_colors, edge_colors=None, face_alpha=1,
                 radius_factor=1):
        """
        """
        assert 0 <= face_alpha <= 1, f"Invalid face_alpha: {face_alpha}"
        assert radius_factor > 0, "radius_factor must be positive"
        self.rad_factor = radius_factor
        self.fc = [mcolors.colorConverter.to_rgba(fc, alpha=face_alpha)
                   for fc in face_colors]
        self.ec = edge_colors
        if edge_colors is None:
            self.ec = ["none" for _ in self.fc]
        self.N = len(self.fc)

    def get_patch(self, width, height, idx, fc, ec):
        """
        """
        w_chunk = width / self.N
        radius = min(w_chunk / 2, height) * self.rad_factor
        xy = (w_chunk * idx + radius, radius)
        patch = plt.Circle(xy, radius, facecolor=fc, edgecolor=ec)
        return patch

    def __call__(self, width, height):
        """
        """
        patches = []
        for i, (fc, ec) in enumerate(zip(self.fc, self.ec)):
            patch = self.get_patch(width, height, i, fc, ec)
            patches.append(patch)
        result = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)
        #
        return result


class MulticolorHandler:
    """
    """
    @staticmethod
    def legend_artist(legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        """
        """
        width, height = handlebox.width, handlebox.height
        patch = orig_handle(width, height)
        handlebox.add_artist(patch)
        return patch
```

Sample usage and image, note that some of the legend handles have `radius_factor=0.5` because the true size would be too small.

```py
ax_handles, ax_labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax_labels.append(AUDIOSET_LABEL)
ax_handles.append(MulticolorCircles([AUDIOSET_COLOR],
                                    face_alpha=LEGEND_SHADOW_ALPHA))
ax_labels.append(FRAUNHOFER_LABEL)
ax_handles.append(MulticolorCircles([FRAUNHOFER_COLOR],
                                    face_alpha=LEGEND_SHADOW_ALPHA))
ax_labels.append(TRAIN_SOURCE_NORMAL_LABEL)
ax_handles.append(MulticolorCircles(SHADOW_COLORS["source"],
                                    face_alpha=LEGEND_SHADOW_ALPHA))
ax_labels.append(TRAIN_TARGET_NORMAL_LABEL)
ax_handles.append(MulticolorCircles(SHADOW_COLORS["target"],
                                    face_alpha=LEGEND_SHADOW_ALPHA))
ax_labels.append(TEST_SOURCE_ANOMALY_LABEL)
ax_handles.append(MulticolorCircles(DOT_COLORS["anomaly_source"],
                                    radius_factor=LEGEND_DOT_RATIO))
ax_labels.append(TEST_TARGET_ANOMALY_LABEL)
ax_handles.append(MulticolorCircles(DOT_COLORS["anomaly_target"],
                                    radius_factor=LEGEND_DOT_RATIO))
#
ax.legend(ax_handles, ax_labels, handlelength=LEGEND_ICON_SIZE,
            borderpad=1.1, labelspacing=1.1,
            handler_map={MulticolorCircles: MulticolorHandler})
```

[image]

Comment: Been searching for a while how to do multicolored circles for a single label. Worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but you can do it (very) manually by placing patches and text yourself on the plot. For instance:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Foo')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])

r1 = mpatches.Rectangle((0.1, 0.1), 0.18, 0.1, fill=False)
r2 = mpatches.Rectangle((0.12, 0.12), 0.03, 0.06, fill=True, color='red')
r3 = mpatches.Rectangle((0.15, 0.12), 0.03, 0.06, fill=True, color='blue')
ax.add_patch(r1)
ax.add_patch(r2)
ax.add_patch(r3)
ax.annotate('Foo', (0.2, 0.13), fontsize='x-large')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[raphael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67870930) uses `PatchCollection`, which drops hatches of its child patches: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22654

I find that directly call `handlebox.add_artist(patch)` after constructing each patch works fine without using `PatchCollection`, and hatches are well-preserved.

```py
# define an object that will be used by the legend
class MulticolorPatch(object):
    def __init__(self, colors, pattern):
        self.colors = colors
        self.pattern = pattern
class MulticolorPatchHandler(object):
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        width, height = handlebox.width, handlebox.height
        for i, c in enumerate(orig_handle.colors):
            patch = plt.Rectangle(
                [
                    width/len(orig_handle.colors) * i - handlebox.xdescent,
                    -handlebox.ydescent,
                ],
                width / len(orig_handle.colors),
                height, 
                facecolor=c, 
                edgecolor='black',
                hatch=orig_handle.pattern,
            )
            if i == 0:
                ret = patch
            handlebox.add_artist(patch)
        return ret
```

### References

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149119/13688160