# Single legend item with two lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to generate a custom `matplotlib` legend which, for each entry has two lines for each label as shown in this example:

[image]

From some research, it seems possible to simply provide two `handles' to the`fig.legend(handles, labels)` method, (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732845/combine-two-pyplot-patches-for-legend) as an example). However, as shown by the following example code, this simply overlays the lines on top of each other.

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

blue_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='r')
green_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], linestyle='--', color='k')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
handles = [(blue_line,green_line)]
labels = ['test'] 
fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, fontsize=20)
```

So, I think I either need to transform one of the `Line2D` objects, or generate a new `Patch` object which contains two lines. However, I can't work out how to do this - is there a simple way to combine two patches, or have I missed a trick in combining the handles?

#### Context

In case this helps others, the context is that I'm using the technique discussed [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html), that is a twin axis which is coloured to show two different plots simultaneously. However, the two lines have the same label, hence why I wanted to combined them together.

Comment: Note that there's an example on the `matplotlib` gallery page that does just this http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/legend_demo5.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the matplotlib legend guide there is a chapter about [custom legend handlers](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handlers). You could adapt it to your needs, e.g. like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase


class AnyObjectHandler(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       x0, y0, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        l1 = plt.Line2D([x0,y0+width], [0.7*height,0.7*height], 
                                                linestyle='--', color='k')
        l2 = plt.Line2D([x0,y0+width], [0.3*height,0.3*height], color='r')
        return [l1, l2]


x = np.linspace(0, 3)
fig, axL = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
axR = axL.twinx()

axL.plot(x, np.sin(x), color='k', linestyle='--')
axR.plot(x, 100*np.cos(x), color='r')

axL.set_ylabel('sin(x)', color='k')
axR.set_ylabel('100 cos(x)', color='r')
axR.tick_params('y', colors='r')

plt.legend([object], ['label'],
           handler_map={object: AnyObjectHandler()})

plt.show()
```

[image]

In order to have multiple such entries, one can supply some tuple of parameters that the `Handler` then uses to draw the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase


class AnyObjectHandler(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       x0, y0, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        l1 = plt.Line2D([x0,y0+width], [0.7*height,0.7*height],
                           linestyle=orig_handle[1], color='k')
        l2 = plt.Line2D([x0,y0+width], [0.3*height,0.3*height], 
                           color=orig_handle[0])
        return [l1, l2]


x = np.linspace(0, 3)
fig, axL = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
axR = axL.twinx()

axL.plot(x, np.sin(x), color='k', linestyle='--')
axR.plot(x, 100*np.cos(x), color='r')

axL.plot(x, .3*np.sin(x), color='k', linestyle=':')
axR.plot(x, 20*np.cos(x), color='limegreen')

axL.set_ylabel('sin(x)', color='k')
axR.set_ylabel('100 cos(x)', color='r')
axR.tick_params('y', colors='r')

plt.legend([("r","--"), ("limegreen",":")], ['label', "label2"],
           handler_map={tuple: AnyObjectHandler()})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks for this. It should be noted than in order to have several different 'sets' of lines once must create different `AnyObject` classes which can be used as the keys.

Comment: I updated the solution for the case where you want to have several such entries.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an inadequate solution I have come to after playing around. I post it in case it helps others, but would prefer to do it properly. It uses two columns and the label of the first as a '/' or one could equally use "and".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 3)
fig, axL = plt.subplots()
axR = axL.twinx()

axL.plot(x, np.sin(x), color='k', label='/')
axR.plot(x, 100*np.cos(x), color='r', label='label')

axL.set_ylabel('sin(x)', color='k')
axR.set_ylabel('100 cos(x)', color='r')
axR.tick_params('y', colors='r')

handlesL, labelsL = axL.get_legend_handles_labels()
handlesR, labelsR = axR.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = handlesL + handlesR
labels = labelsL + labelsR
axR.legend(handles, labels, loc='lower center', ncol=2, fontsize=16,
           handletextpad=0.4, columnspacing=0.4)
```

[image]