# Python - Matplotlib: Define Individual Legend Entries

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

When I plot the following:

```
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],'g',label='Solid')
plt.plot([0,1],[.5,1],'b',label='Solid')
plt.plot([0,1],[1,0],'g--',label='Dashed')
plt.plot([0,1],[.5,0],'b--',label='Dashed')
plt.legend()
```

I get this image:

[image]

For me, this is too much legend text. Does anyone know, how I can join the solid blue and green line and the dashed blue and green line to reduce the legend to two entries with a green/blue (preferably the one on top of the other) line and the corresponding text?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative have a look at the solution in this post:
[Single legend item with two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752309/single-legend-item-with-two-lines)

A bit more complicated though

Comment: Hi @DZurico. It's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the possible signatures of [`legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html), i.e. `legend(handles, labels)`.

It is also well described in the [Legend Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#controlling-the-legend-entries).

```
line1,  = plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],'g',label='Solid')
line2,  = plt.plot([0,1],[.5,1],'b',label='Solid')
plt.plot([0,1],[1,0],'g--',label='Dashed')
plt.plot([0,1],[.5,0],'b--',label='Dashed')
plt.legend((line1, line2), ('green', 'blue'))
plt.show()
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Hi @ascripter. Thanks for your input, but DZurico linked me to the solution to what I wanted.