# How to show one legend for multiple same label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is plotting a time series graph in which colour categories the age group and label categories the location.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.use('TkAgg')  # !IMPORTANT

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([93497, 137558, 158293, 180411, 183457, 187016, 189596],
        marker='.', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label='Hong Kong', color="bisque")
ax.plot([67594, 112486, 130558, 149890, 157317, 163262, 165828],
        marker='v', linestyle='-', label='Kowloon', color="bisque")
ax.plot([58093, 102680, 121633, 138414, 144665, 149776, 152765],
        marker='*', linestyle='-', label='New Territories', color="bisque")

ax.plot([101779, 140103, 160860, 176330, 183330, 182458, 184591],
        marker='.', markersize=5, linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label='Hong Kong', color="teal")
ax.plot([81941, 115792, 131061, 147161, 153582, 160379, 161225],
        marker='v', markersize=5, linestyle='-', label='Kowloon', color="teal")
ax.plot([56305, 91942, 106554, 120067, 125490, 132070, 136451],
        marker='*', markersize=5, linestyle='-', label='New Territories', color="teal")
ax.set_ylabel('$HKD/sq. m.')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

How to have one legend only for each label, so no duplicated legend name.

For example, instead of "Hong Kong", "Kowloon", "New Territories", "Hong Kong", "Kowloon", "New Territories"

Showing "Hong Kong", "Kowloon", "New Territories" only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41765095/6660373

Try tweaking as per your need.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase


class AnyObjectHandler(HandlerBase):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       x0, y0, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        print(orig_handle)
        l1 = plt.Line2D([x0,y0+width], [0.9*height,0.9*height], markersize=10,
                           linestyle=None, color="bisque", marker=orig_handle[0])
        l2 = plt.Line2D([x0,y0+width], [0.1*height,0.1*height], 
                           color="teal", marker=orig_handle[0])
        return [l1, l2]


x = np.linspace(0, 3)
fig, axL = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
axR = axL
axM = axR

axL.plot([93497, 137558, 158293, 180411, 183457, 187016, 189596],
        marker='.', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label='Hong Kong', color="bisque")
axR.plot([67594, 112486, 130558, 149890, 157317, 163262, 165828],
        marker='v', linestyle='-', label='Kowloon', color="bisque")
axM.plot([58093, 102680, 121633, 138414, 144665, 149776, 152765],
        marker='*', linestyle='-', label='New Territories', color="bisque")

axL.plot([101779, 140103, 160860, 176330, 183330, 182458, 184591],
        marker='.', markersize=5, linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label='Hong Kong', color="teal")
axR.plot([81941, 115792, 131061, 147161, 153582, 160379, 161225],
        marker='v', markersize=5, linestyle='-', label='Kowloon', color="teal")
axM.plot([56305, 91942, 106554, 120067, 125490, 132070, 136451],
        marker='*', markersize=5, linestyle='-', label='New Territories', color="teal")

plt.legend([(".",), ("v",), ("*",)], ['Hong Kong', 'Kowloon', 'New Territories'],
           handler_map={tuple: AnyObjectHandler()})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put `label=None` for the lines you don't want in the legend. Example code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# mpl.use('TkAgg')  # !IMPORTANT

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([93497, 137558, 158293, 180411, 183457, 187016, 189596],
        marker='.', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label='Hong Kong', color="bisque")
ax.plot([67594, 112486, 130558, 149890, 157317, 163262, 165828],
        marker='v', linestyle='-', label='Kowloon', color="bisque")
ax.plot([58093, 102680, 121633, 138414, 144665, 149776, 152765],
        marker='*', linestyle='-', label='New Territories', color="bisque")

ax.plot([101779, 140103, 160860, 176330, 183330, 182458, 184591],
        marker='.', markersize=5, linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label=None, color="teal")
ax.plot([81941, 115792, 131061, 147161, 153582, 160379, 161225],
        marker='v', markersize=5, linestyle='-', label=None, color="teal")
ax.plot([56305, 91942, 106554, 120067, 125490, 132070, 136451],
        marker='*', markersize=5, linestyle='-', label=None, color="teal")
ax.set_ylabel('$HKD/sq. m.')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But then the cooler of the legend is yellow, looks like it missed the green line, is there a way to represent the label using the legend?